# dates in x axis are superimposed - plot shows the last entered data 2 times (when not using setXAxisMax)

Tags: android, achartengine

(I fixed some issues with saving and loading regarding my previous posts)

I am saving some data (mydata) and the date as strings (dates_Strings).

In graph activity I load data and dates.And I convert dates_Strings to dates in order to use them in the plot.

Now , while entering some data for example "1","2","3" in 10/05/13 I am getting the following image.

[image: first image]

All good until now.

If I try to enter some more data ("3,4,7") in another date (13/05/13) I am getting this image.

[image: second image]

The dates are superimposed.

The MainActivity :

The code:

```
        //copy the dates_asString to date (Dates) in order to use them in TimeSeries
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy",Locale.US);
        Date convertedDate;
        try{
       for (int k=0;k<mydata.size();k++){
        convertedDate = formatter.parse(dates_Strings.get(k));
        date.clear();
        date.add(convertedDate);
        Log.d("line","convertedDate :"+convertedDate);
       }
        }catch ...


        //TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Showing data");
        //for (int i=0;i<mydata.size();i++){    
        //  series.add(i,mydata.get(i));    
        //}

        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Showing data");
           for (int i=0;i<mydata.size();i++){   
        series.add(i,mydata.get(i));    
    }


        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset=new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        dataset.addSeries(series);



        XYSeriesRenderer renderer =new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        ...

        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer =new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
        ...
        mRenderer.setXRoundedLabels(false);
        mRenderer.setXLabels(0);


        //mRenderer.setXAxisMax(mydata.size()); 

        for (int i=0;i<mydata.size();i++){
            mRenderer.addXTextLabel(i,dates_Strings.get(i));

        }
```

I put in setXAxisMax the value 14/05/2013 and I entered data in 10/05 and 13/05 for example.

When I use setXAxisMin the plot is completely empty.

Another weird problem occurs if I don't use setXAxisMax  . I enter "1" and "2" as data but the plot shows the "2" (second data) in two points. :

[image: third image]

------------------UPDATE----------------------------------------

Ok, I think the problem lies during saving the data in the file.

The user enters some data (mydata) in an edittext field and then presses the save button which saves that data together with the current date.

For example , user enters "1" and presses "save".

user enters "2" and presses "save".

So, I have data "1" and "2" in the same date (08/05/13).

I want to save one instance of the date (because it is the same date) in order to have one point (date) in x axis and 2 points (1 and 2) in y axis.

I am saving as:

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
              for (int i=0;i<mydata.size();i++){

           bw.write(mydata.get(i)+","+dates_Strings.get(i)+"\n");
              }
```

I thought sth like:

```
      for (int i=1;i<mydata.size();i++){

          bw.write(mydata.get(i)+",");

    while (!(dates_Strings.get(i).equals(dates_Strings.get(i-1))))   

              bw.write(dates_Strings.get(i)+"\n");
      }
```

but it saves only the last entered data..

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a wrong usage of the `TimeSeries`. You are calling `series.add(i, something)` where `something` is `mydata.get(i)` in your code. This means that the method `add(double x, double y)` inherited by `TimeSeries` from `XYSeries` is called, so `x` in your case ranges between `0` and `mydata.size() - 1`.

Just make sure you are correctly calling the `add(Date x, double value)` method in `TimeSeries`.

Comment: :If i use series.add(dates.get(i),mydata.get(i)) I am getting empty plot.

Comment: Your example is incomplete and I cannot guess what the mydata values are. As long as you don't provide an example that I can run and test, I cannot help you. If I cannot help you, I doubt anyone else can. Just setup an example with hardcoded values or something.

Comment: :I can send you if you want the whole working code.It is small.Upload it here?I don't  have problem.The mydata is a double list.User enters data in an edittext field.

Comment: Just simplify it. Instead of sending me to a file I don't have, just hardcode some values.

Comment: I uploaded the whole working code.I remind you that the user may enter data during a day or after some days and so on.And I want to keep all these data.Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what mydata.csv is. Simplify the example if you need help.

Comment: Why are you using a TimeSeries when building a scatter chart? Use a simple XYSeries.

Comment: And call setXAxisMax(mydata.size())

Comment: :mydata.csv is the file where I save all the data (i want to save them in a file also).I am sorry ,I will come back tomorrow because I must go now.

Comment: :Can you show me an example if you want with XYSeries in my code please?

Comment: Just replace TimeSeries with XYSeries.

Comment: :I am confused now.You say above "replace TimeSeries with XYSeries" and in the answer "make sure you are correctly calling the add(Date x, double value) method in TimeSeries".Can you show me how to do it please because I don't have experience as you can see.Thank you.

Comment: Switch to XYSeries and keep using the current approach for adding data. Just make sure that you call setXAxisMax(mydata.size());

Comment: :I deleted the TimeSeries and I used:  XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Showing data");
        for (int i=0;i<mydata.size();i++){ 
   series.add(i,mydata.get(i)); 
  }. Also, I used setXAxisMax(mydata.size()) and I am getting again the last figure I have in my post.

Comment: OK. I give up until you will be able to write a small piece of code that adds hardcoded values to a dataset. I don't need UI, csv files or other such stuff. Just a small sample that will help me replicate your problem.

Comment: :Ok, I really don't know what else you want me to write.I think I have it all clear.I have all the code,I told you what I tried.I told you I haven't experience.Anyway , I appreciate your help until know ,but really I don't know what else to give you.