# I am using achart engine and want to add starting and ending date

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

![enter image description here][1]  I am using achartengine for graphs plotting in android and i want to add starting     ending date just like in snapshoot.Make enable this code with date and save data.Achar engine basically use for graphs so help mei how to achieve this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private GraphicalView mChart;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    openChart();
}

private void openChart(){

    int count = 5;
    Date[] dt = new Date[5];
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 10, i+1);
        dt[i] = gc.getTime();
    }

    int[] visits = { 2000,2500,2700,2100,2800};
    int[] views = {2200, 2700, 2900, 2800, 3200};

    // Creating TimeSeries for Visits
    TimeSeries visitsSeries = new TimeSeries("Visits");

    // Creating TimeSeries for Views
    TimeSeries viewsSeries = new TimeSeries("Views");

    // Adding data to Visits and Views Series
    for(int i=0;i<dt.length;i++){
        visitsSeries.add(dt[i], visits[i]);
        viewsSeries.add(dt[i],views[i]);
    }

    // Creating a dataset to hold each series
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

    // Adding Visits Series to the dataset
    dataset.addSeries(visitsSeries);

    // Adding Visits Series to dataset
    dataset.addSeries(viewsSeries);

    // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize visitsSeries
    XYSeriesRenderer visitsRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    visitsRenderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    visitsRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    visitsRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    visitsRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    visitsRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

    // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize viewsSeries
    XYSeriesRenderer viewsRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    viewsRenderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    viewsRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    viewsRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    viewsRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    viewsRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

    // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

    multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Visits vs Views Chart");
    multiRenderer.setXTitle("Days");
    multiRenderer.setYTitle("Count");
    multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);

    // Adding visitsRenderer and viewsRenderer to multipleRenderer

    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(visitsRenderer);
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(viewsRenderer);

    // Getting a reference to LinearLayout of the MainActivity Layout
    LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart_container);

    // Creating a Time Chart
    mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(getBaseContext(),  dataset,         multiRenderer,"dd-MMM-yyyy");

    multiRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
    multiRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(10);

    // Setting a click event listener for the graph
    mChart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

            SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChart.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();

            if (seriesSelection != null) {
                int seriesIndex = seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex();
                String selectedSeries="Visits";
                if(seriesIndex==0)
                    selectedSeries = "Visits";
                else
                    selectedSeries = "Views";

                // Getting the clicked Date ( x value )
                long clickedDateSeconds = (long) seriesSelection.getXValue();
                Date clickedDate = new Date(clickedDateSeconds);
                String strDate = formatter.format(clickedDate);

                // Getting the y value
                int amount = (int) seriesSelection.getValue();

                // Displaying Toast Message
                Toast.makeText(
                    getBaseContext(),
                    selectedSeries + " on "  + strDate + " : " + amount ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        // Adding the Line Chart to the LinearLayout
        chartContainer.addView(mChart);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
![Here is a image ][2]
```

http://apps.opera.com/editimg/working_hours_android_os.png

Comment: Please re-write your question.  I cannot understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: (http://apps.opera.com/editimg/working_hours_android_os.png)
what i want click on this URL.I want just date integrate.

Comment: @buddy9:Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To add minumim and maximum dates in x axis (if it is what you want) :

```
multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);  //in order to define custom labels

multiRenderer.setXAxisMin(initial_date.size()); 
multiRenderer.setXAxisMax(final_date.size());
```

where final_date must some a date after your last date.

UPDATE:

You must use:  `multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(1,"10/04");`

And you can loop (assuming dates is a list which holds dates) :

```
for (int i=0;i<dates.size();i++){
    multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i,dates.get(i));
}
```

But you must use multiRenderer.setXLabels(0); before the above in order to define your labels.

Comment: So it sounds like you finally understood the solution I provided you a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418225/dates-in-x-axis-are-superimposed-plot-shows-the-last-entered-data-2-times-whe

Comment: @Dan:I understood that from the first time but the problem is that it didn't work for me.The post is still open,I haven't found a solution.

Comment: @buddy9:Your welcome!(if the answer covered you ,you can accept it)